New vacuum breaker drips after shutting off the hose and releasing water off the hose
In my garage, I have a faucet with anti-siphon valve. I believe they call it vacuum breaker. Since it was leaking when I turn on the faucet, I replaced it. It stopped leaking with new valve but when I turned on with the hose attached, it leaks after shutting off the faucet and releasing the water out of hose by pressing the hose spigot.
Is this normal? It doesn’t spray. It drips about two table spoons worth water. Should I have lift up the hose higher than the valve? Please help. This is a house I just bought and never had a facet with a valve before.

This sounds like normal operation. The vacuum breaker should not leak when the valve is open and delivering water through the hose. When you turn off the valve the pressure on the supply side of the vacuum breaker may drop below the pressure on the outlet side. When this happens the vacuum breaker is supposed to admit air but a small amount of water can "backflow" out the holes in the vacuum breaker. This is normal operation.

@JimStewart -- that's an answer, right there.

This sounds like normal operation. The vacuum breaker should not leak when the valve is open and delivering water through the hose. When you turn off the valve the pressure on the supply side of the vacuum breaker may drop below the pressure on the outlet side. When this happens the vacuum breaker is supposed to admit air but a small amount of water could flow out the holes in the vacuum breaker. I think this is normal operation.
If the hose is below the level of the vacuum breaker and unrestricted at its end by a small orifice, then when the valve is turned off I would expect that water level on the delivery side of the vacuum breaker would drop and you would not get much water out the relief air admittance holes.
But if the end of the hose was restricted so that pressure built up in the hose while the water was flowing, then when the valve is turned off I would expect some water might backflow out the air admittance holes. Also after the valve was turned off if you elevated the hose above the vacuum breaker, then water would be expected to flow out the air admittance holes.
